# Add information to both end of multiple strings

Tags: python

I attempt to add more information to elements in a list.

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

add prefix and postfix to elements.
newlist = []

```
for i in mylist:
    i += '.md'
    i = 'py_' +
    newlist.append(i)
```

Output:

```
['py_a.md', 'py_b.md', 'py_c.md']
```

or

```
[ 'py_'+i+'.md' for i in mylist]
```

How to handle it with other one single code?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Exactly.. didn't see the list comprehension at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, your list comprehension is perfect. You could also use a `map` I suppose.

```
map(lambda i: "py_"+i+".md", mylist)
```

but why mess with it when you've got it in a listcomp?